# Dynamically replacing backward slash '\' with foward slash '/'

Tags: java, path

I am getting my browse file location from withing the system , so the generated string path is as

```
String path = "C:\Documents and Settings\abcd\Desktop\d.txt";
```

My input is coming from browse button , so input file path is dynamic. 
I need to Replacing backward slash '\' to foward slash '/' , so that i could use the path further in my coding .
I need to do this dynamically . Can anybody tell me how.

My desired output is

```
C:/Documents and Settings/abcd/Desktop/d.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Correct Answer ---

Following is the correct answer for the above mentioned question ---
    String newPath = path.replaceAll("\\", "/");

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: If you are getting the path dynamically, you don't need to replace the backslash. If your String is a literal like you have, it will produce a compilation error.

Comment: I am getting my path dynamically as mentioned above, which is producing error if used again to locate the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll` to replace a substring in a string :

```
String path = "C:\Documents and Settings\abcd\Desktop\d.txt";
String goodPath = path.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement will not compile without escaping the backslash characters. The backslash character is used to denote the beginning of a control character or unicode literal so must be escaped to represent the `\` literal value itself.

You can do

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\abcd\\Desktop\\d.txt";
String newPath = path.replace("\\", "/");
```

Comment: Ignoring that this is a dup ... s/replace/replaceAll/

Comment: From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for replace  _Returns a new string resulting from replacing **all** occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar._

Comment: @BrianRoach: `replaceAll` takes a regex.

Comment: Can u eleborate as how are u changing String path = "C:\Documents and Settings\abcd\Desktop\d.txt" to "C:\\Documents and Settings\\abcd\\Desktop\\d.txt".

Comment: You mean why? - sure `\\`` is used is denote the beginning of the control character so you you need to escape it in a `String`.